# Solving non-linear set of symbolic equations with SymPy (Python)

Tags: python, sympy

I'm trying to solve the following system of non-linear equations using SymPy:

[image]

where [image] are the unknowns (the rest are known parameter symbols).

My code is:

```
import sympy as sy
sy.init_printing()

m, v0, k, g, R, u, v = sy.symbols('m v0 k g R u v')

sy.nonlinsolve([0.5*m*v0**2 - m*g*2*R - 0.5*m*v**2 - 0.5*k*m*u**2, 
     m*v0 - m*v - k*m*u, m*g - m*((u+v)**2)/R], [v0, v, u] )
```

But I'm getting infinite process time and have to interrupt the kernel.
Also, I know that the solution for v0 is:

[image]

Is there a better way to solve it? Maybe another solver?
Or maybe there is a way to get Python check if the solution I have works?

Thank you !!!

Comment: If we cancel out all the `m`s from all sides of all equations and substitute the second and third equation in the first one, we still get an equation that contains both `u` and `v` in it. So I think you system of equations has  no unique solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've got it using some added flags into the solve function:

When I did:

```
import sympy as sy
sy.init_printing()

m, v0, k, g, R, u, v = sy.symbols('m v0 k g R u v')   #Define Symbols

sy.solve((0.5*m*v0**2 - m*g*2*R - 0.5*m*v**2 - 0.5*k*m*u**2, 
         m*v0 + m*v - k*m*u, m*g - m*((u+v)**2)/R), [v0,u,v] ,
         force=True, manual=True, set=True)
```

It worked!! the `'force'` and `'manual'` flags did the trick!